# Filemaker Server 11 - Error login when using an account from an external domain group in Active Directory

Tags: filemaker

I've been trying to make users that belong to certain security group created in Active Directory to have Admin access to the Admin console. In FileMaker it is suppossed to be able to achieve this by enabling "Use external group" in the "[General Settings/Admin Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXyIE.png)" tab. Let's say I have this group in AD called "FM_Admins", this very group is defined in the box "Use external group", I hit "Test External Group" and it displays "Status validated".

But when I try to login with the domain account that is part of the security group, it doesn't let me in. I've tried using the user with different domain login types e.g. EXAMPLE\username or username@example.net

If anyone have a pointer, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Try username without specifying the domain, although as I mentioned below, I am not sure if AD supported for Admin Console

Comment: Did that: I tried using only the username first, but it didn't let me log in. But I guess you´re right; maybe Admin console isn't able to authenticate external users from AD. Of course Admin Console settings (see my attached image) states that: "In addition to authenticating with the Admin Console account, allow Admin Console users to login with accounts that are members of the external group." Though, it doesn't state that they must be in the Local server or the Domain controller. (By the way, this server is enrolled in a domain, and obviously the local users or groups are disabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Admin console does accept AD accounts to be authenticated. I've just tried it in a virtual domain controller and it worked, so where's the catch? These accounts **MUST** be in the Administrators group. Of course I was trying with regular accounts, as they are the only kind of accounts I'm allowed to have, according my company's security policies. Anyways, thank you, Nicolai, for your answer.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for posting back. BTW, you can select your own answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this functionality was designed to use a local computer group and not AD. Try to add FM_Admins as a group to this server.